# Scraping text in h3 and div tags using beautifulSoup, Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have no experience with python, BeautifulSoup, Selenium etc. but I'm eager to scrape data from a website and store as a csv file.
A single sample of data I need is coded as follows (a single row of data).

```
<div class="box effect">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <h3>HEADING</h3>
        <div><i class="fa user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;NAME</div>
        <div><i class="fa phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;MOBILE</div>
        <div><i class="fa mobile-phone fa-2"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NUMBER</div>
        <div><i class="fa address"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XYZ_ADDRESS</div>
    <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="padding:10px;padding-left:0px;"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="www.link_to_another_page.com"><i class="fa search-plus"></i> &nbsp;more info</a></div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The output I need is
 `Heading,NAME,MOBILE,NUMBER,XYZ_ADDRESS`

I found those data don't have a id or class yet being in website as general text.
I'm trying BeautifulSoup and Python Selenium separately for that, where I got stuck to extract in both the methods as no tutorials I saw, guided me to extract text from these  and  tags

My code using BeautifulSoup

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

MAX = 2

'''with open("lg.csv", "a") as f:
  w=csv.writer(f)'''
##for i in range(1,MAX+1)
url="http://www.example_site.com"

page=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

for h in soup.find_all('h3'):
    print(h.get('h3'))
```

My selenium code

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
MAX_PAGE_NUM = 2
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM+1):
  url = "http://www.example_site.com"
  driver.get(url)
  name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class = "col-lg-10"]/h3')
  #contact = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="item-price"]')
#  phone = 
#  mobile = 
#  address =
#  print(len(buyers))
#  num_page_items = len(buyers)
#  with open('res.csv','a') as f:
#    for i in range(num_page_items):
#      f.write(buyers[i].text + "," + prices[i].text + "\n")
  print (name)          
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors to find the data you need.
In your case `div > h3 ~ div` will find all `div` elements that are directly inside a `div` element and are proceeded by a `h3` element.

```
import bs4

page= """
<div class="box effect">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <h3>HEADING</h3>
    <div><i class="fa user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;NAME</div>
    <div><i class="fa phone"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;MOBILE</div>
    <div><i class="fa mobile-phone fa-2"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;NUMBER</div>
    <div><i class="fa address"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XYZ_ADDRESS</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
"""

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

# find all div elements that are inside a div element
# and are proceeded by an h3 element
selector = 'div > h3 ~ div'

# find elements that contain the data we want
found = soup.select(selector)

# Extract data from the found elements
data = [x.text.split(';')[-1].strip() for x in found]

for x in data:
    print(x)
```

Edit: To scrape the text in heading..

```
heading = soup.find('h3') 
heading_data = heading.text
print(heading_data)
```

Edit: Or you can get the heading and other div elements at once by using a selector like this: `div.col-lg-10 > *`. This finds all elements inside a `div` element that belongs to `col-lg-10` class.

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

# find all elements inside a div element of class col-lg-10
selector = 'div.col-lg-10 > *'

# find elements that contain the data we want
found = soup.select(selector)

# Extract data from the found elements
data = [x.text.split(';')[-1].strip() for x in found]

for x in data:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Thanks..very informative but what does ~ in selector = 'div > h3 ~ div' mean? also in selector = 'div.col-lg-10 > *' what if col-lg-10 had spaces? how do I express that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So it seemed quite nice:

```
    #  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # by Faguiro #
    # run using Python 3.8.6  on Linux#
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    # insert your site here
    url= input("Enter the url-->")

    #use requests
    r = requests.get(url)
    content = r.content

    #soup!
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

    #find all tag in the soup.
    heading = soup.find_all("h3")

    #print(heading) <--- result...

    #...ptonic organization!
    n=len(heading)
    for x in range(n): 
        print(str.strip(heading[x].text))
```

Dependencies:
On terminal (linux):

sudo apt-get install python3-bs4

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

MAX = 2

'''with open("lg.csv", "a") as f:
  w=csv.writer(f)'''
##for i in range(1,MAX+1)
url="http://www.example_site.com"

page=requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

print(soup.text)
```