# extract content wherever we have div tag followed by hearder tag by using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract div tags and header tags when they are together.
ex:

```
<h3>header</h3>
<div>some text here
    <ul>
             <li>list</li>
             <li>list</li>
             <li>list</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I tried solution provided in below link.
 here the header tag inside div tag...
but my requirement is div tag after header tag.

[Scraping text in h3 and div tags using beautifulSoup, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933679/scraping-text-in-h3-and-div-tags-using-beautifulsoup-python)

also i tried something like this but not worked

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')


found = soup..find_all({"h3", "div"})
```

I need content from H3 tag and all the content inside div tag where ever these two combination exists.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS selector `h3:has(+div)` - this will select all `<h3>` which have `div` immediately after it:

```
data = '''<h3>header</h3>
<div>some text here
    <ul>
             <li>list</li>
             <li>list</li>
             <li>list</li>
     </ul>
</div>
<h3>This header is not selected</h3>
<p>Beacause this is P tag, not DIV</p>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for h3 in soup.select('h3:has(+div)'):
    print('Header:')
    print(h3.text)
    print('Next <div>:')
    print(h3.find_next_sibling('div').get_text(separator=",", strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Header:
header
Next <div>:
some text here,list,list,list
```

Further reading:

**[CSS Selectors reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Comment: great!! it worked... thank you... is there a way to retain list and paragraph by excluding html tags...

Comment: @Praveen do you want only text of the `<div>` after `<h3>`? Then do `h3.find_next_sibling('div').text`