# Extract text from <ol> after specific <h3> in a specific <div> with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text from a certain 'ol' in this [page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/add#English) using BeautifulSoup. The information I want to get is under a specific 'div' with a certain class but I want the text from the list items that immediately appear after a certain 'h3' that includes a 'span' with a class and id. See the picture:
[image]
The output should be:

```
Verb
1. (transitive) To join or unite (e.g. one thing to another, or as several particulars) so as to increase the number, augment the quantity or enlarge the magnitude, or so as to form into one aggregate.
2. To sum up; to put together mentally.
...
```

What I have done so far is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

url = urllib.urlopen('https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/add#English')
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

main_div = soup.findAll('div',attrs={"class":"mw-parser-output"})
for x in main_div:
    all_h3 = x.findAll('h3')
    all_ol = x.findAll('ol')
```

The first answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46933679/scraping-text-in-h3-and-div-tags-using-beautifulsoup-python) might be related but I didn't know how to edit it for my task.

Comment: So, what exactly is wrong with the code you wrote already? Did you run it? (there is a typo in `main_dev`, so it would not run verbatim.) Please include all the necessary information in this post as _text_, not in images or external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of BeautifulSoup, you could use `lxml.html` and XPath expressions.

**Python**

```
import requests
import io
from lxml import html

res = requests.get("https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/add#English")

tree = html.parse(io.StringIO(res.text))

outputs = []

h3 = tree.xpath("//h3[span[@class = 'mw-headline' and @id = 'Verb']]")[0]

outputs.append(h3.xpath("span")[0].text)

ol = h3.xpath("following::ol[1]")[0]

outputs.append(ol.text_content())

print(outputs)
```

**Output**

```
['Verb',
 '(transitive) To join or unite (e.g. one thing to another, or as several particulars) so as to increase the number, augment the quantity, or enlarge the magnitude, or so as to form into one aggregate.\nTo sum up; to put together mentally.\n1689, John Locke, An Essay Concerning Human Understanding\n […] as easily as he can add together the ideas of two days or two years.\nto add numbers\n(transitive) To combine elements of (something) into one quantity.\nto add a column of numbers\n(transitive) To give by way of increased possession (to someone); to bestow (on).\n1611, King James Version, Genesis 30:24:\nThe LORD shall add to me another son.\n1667, John Milton, Paradise Lost:\nBack to thy punishment, False fugitive, and to thy speed add wings.\n(transitive) To append (e,g, a statement); to say further information.\n1855, Thomas Babington Macaulay, The History of England from the Accession of James the Second, volume 3, page 37\xa0[1]:\nHe added that he would willingly consent to the entire abolition of the tax\n1900, L. Frank Baum, The Wonderful Wizard of Oz Chapter 23\n"Bless your dear heart," she said, "I am sure I can tell you of a way to get back to Kansas." Then she added, "But, if I do, you must give me the Golden Cap."\n(intransitive) To make an addition; to augment; to increase.\n1611, King James Version, 1 Kings 12:14:\nI will add to your yoke\n2013 June 29,  “A punch in the gut”, in  The Economist, volume 407, number 8842, page 72-3:Mostly, the microbiome is beneficial. […] Research over the past few years, however, has implicated it in diseases from atherosclerosis to asthma to autism. Dr Yoshimoto and his colleagues would like to add liver cancer to that list.\nIt adds to our anxiety.\n(intransitive, mathematics) To perform the arithmetical operation of addition.\nHe adds rapidly.\n(intransitive, video games) To summon minions or reinforcements.\nTypically, a hostile mob will add whenever it\'s within the aggro radius of a player.']
```